# Get distinct values from a datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `DataTable` with values:

```
ID  NameID  Name
1   1       qwe
2   2       ert  
3   2       ert  
4   3       dffg 
5   3       dffg
```

I want to get a `DataTable` containing distinct rows like this:

```
ID  NameID  Name
1   1       qwe
2   2       ert
4   3       dffg
```

How can this be achieved using LINQ or other?

Comment: How do you want to determine which IDs to pick when there are duplicates?  Always the lowest ID in the group?

Comment: I tried the below LINQ
dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("NameID")).Distinct();
But results are not coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rows = tbl.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row).ToList();
tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
tbl.Columns.Add("NameID", typeof(Int32));
tbl.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));

rows.GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("NameID"))                
    .Select(rr => rows.First(rw => rw.Field<Int32>("NameID") == rr.Key))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(rname => tbl.Rows.Add(new object []
        {                                                 
            rname.Field<Int32>("ID"),
            rname.Field<Int32>("NameID"),
            rname.Field<String>("Name"),                    
        }));
```

---

Test data setup:

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Columns.Add("ID", typeof (Int32));
tbl.Columns.Add("NameID", typeof (Int32));
tbl.Columns.Add("Name", typeof (String));

tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1, "qwe" });
tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 2, "ert" });
tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 2, "ert" });
tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 3, "dffg" });
tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, 3, "dffg" });
```

Comment: It will return Name column only. OP needs all columns.

Comment: @Upendra Chaudhari  : yep, missed that point in the question. Updated my query.

Comment: @Upendra Chaudhari : Does you verified code snippet after the YOUR modifications? it returns 8 rows!

Comment: ok, I believed those lines was by mistake cause same lines I got in 2nd test data setup block. sorry for that.

Comment: @Upendra Chaudhari : ok no problems, basically these lines allows setup empty data grid with the same schema, it would be cleaner if we can use something like Rows.Clear()

Answer (score 0):

Assign the datatable to a dataview and with the dataview object we can use RowFilter as follows.

```
                Dim DTb As New DataTable()
                DataView dView= new DataView(DTb); 
                dView.RowFilter = strCondition.ToString //strCondition contains the condition to filter
```

The strCondition will contain the Conditions to filter, and after filtering reassign the dataview to the datatable as follows

```
                DTb = dView.ToTable()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 var result = from ele in dt.AsEnumerable()
               group ele by ele["NameID"] into g
               select g.FirstOrDefault();

  foreach (var t in result)
     Console.WriteLine(t[0] + " " + t[1] + " " + t[2]);
```